# How to programatically open a PDF with a User password

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, password-protection

This is related to my  [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581578/how-to-disable-function-keys-in-a-pdf-displayed-in-a-jsp-using-object-and-henc)...  hope this one has a solution.

The requirement is to display a password-protected PDF in the browser but to pass the User password programatically. I create a PDF using Jasper and set the user password as follows:
      exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);

As soon as the PDF is created, it has to be displayed in the screen. While displaying in the browser, the user should not be prompted to key in the password ans hence the password should be supplied by the application However, if the user downloads the PDF and then tries to open it, he should be prompted to enter the password.
[Edit]: I am looking for an approach that does NOT involve licensed tools

Comment: why can't you seperate the browser version and make it pwd free ?

Comment: @TechExchange the problem is because, the save option cannot be blocked at the browser. So if I create a browser version without password, the pdf could be downloaded and then can be opened without a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether something of this is possible. On the browser the pdf is opened by a Plugin - usually Adobe Reader plug-in. There are also other makes apart from Adobe Reader. Chrome has it own plugin.

On the browser when it detects any  PDF file - the rendering plugin takes over - and this is browser specific. You hardly have any control.

Easy alternative is to show the same content in a web page - probably a modal window if the content is sensitive and give a link to download the password protected pdf file

my 2c

Comment: @ basav, reg. the alternate you have mentioned, "probably a modal window if the content is sensitive", when the pdf is displayed it prompts for a password, which I want to avoid. If i have to avoid the prompt, then the password protection should be removed. That means, the pdf can be saved without a password. So, keep going in circles! :) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. What I meant was instead of opening the PDF directly in the browser, just show contents of the PDF as a web page in a modal window.

Comment: Could not find any solution. Decided to have a HTML version for view purposes.

Answer (score 4):

You can open a password protected PDF using the PDF.JS library.

```
PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url, password: pdf_password }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
    // success
}).catch(function(error) {
    // incorrect password

    // error is an object having 3 properties : name, message & code
});
```

I've written a blog post on it, also containing a demo. This is the link : http://usefulangle.com/post/22/pdfjs-tutorial-2-viewing-a-password-protected-pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdf.js of mozilla to render password protected PDF. The below url that will prompt for password, until the correct password is given. The password for the pdf is "test".

http://learnnewhere.unaux.com/pdfViewer/passwordviewer.html

Here is the sample code for prompting password

```
pdfJs.onPassword = function (updatePassword, reason) { 
      if (reason === 1) { // need a password
            var new_password= prompt('Please enter a password:');
            updatePassword(new_password);
        } else { // Invalid password
            var new_password= prompt('Invalid! Please enter a password:');
            updatePassword(new_password);
        }
   };
```

If you want to close the password prompt on unsuccessful password attempts you can remove the else part(// Invalid password).

You could get the complete code from here https://github.com/learnnewhere/simpleChatApp/tree/master/pdfViewer

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout PDF.js, an open source client based PDF renderer that also has support for encrypted PDFs.
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

This means you will have to put your password somewhere in the javascript though, so you will have to disguise it, but it should do the trick :)